# How to detect duplicates of photos (even if the duplicate is of lower resolution) and how to keep only the higher-res copy?

Tags: photo-management, duplicate, whatsapp

Perusing thousands of photos from my smartphone transferred to my computer is a bit of a challenge. Separating the wheat from the chaff is a time consuming late-night endeavor. What makes this particularly challenging is [WhatsApp](https://www.whatsapp.com/), as it is configured on my phone (by default) sends/receives compressed, lower-res images, rather than full-res. Sharing a photo taken by one's own smartphone would, to my understanding, leave the full-res photo on the phone and additionally create and save a compressed, lower-res and renamed copy of the sent photo in a WhatsApp directory, effectively creating a lower-res duplicate.

As the first iteration of my envisaged workflow I'd like to select unique photos only (over a range of folders and sub-folders). If a given photo exists more than once (either at the same size (same resolution) or at different sizes (different resolutions), I'd like to select only one copy and explicitly only a copy of the highest available resolution (ignoring all lower-res copies).

Building on these two related questions

- [How can I find duplicate photos?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4072/how-can-i-find-duplicate-photos/4076)
  and
- [How does Shotwell detect duplicates?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/509133/how-does-shotwell-detect-duplicates)

How could I accomplish this in a jiffy?

---

The upshot / meaning of this exercise would be to include in the initial photo selection also photos *received* in WhatsApp - as long as these are unique and no higher-res copy exists elsewhere (on my phone / computer).

---

Further related links / resources:

- https://www.linux.com/learn/how-sort-and-remove-duplicate-photos-Linux
- http://www.visipics.info/index.php?title=Main_Page ("VisiPics has been tested successfully with Wine on Linux")
- https://www.howtogeek.com/117559/how-to-banish-duplicate-photos-with-visipic/
- https://pictureecho.com/ (Windows only)
- https://www.techpout.com/best-duplicate-photo-finder-and-cleaner-software/
- https://web.archive.org/web/20201126221814/https://blogs.systweak.com/5-duplicate-photo-finder-tools-to-delete-duplicate-photos/
- **https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/40552/i-need-a-program-that-can-find-duplicate-images-different-resolutions-and-repl**
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13091603/find-duplicate-images-of-different-sizes
- https://www.mindgems.com/products/VS-Duplicate-Image-Finder/VSDIF-About.htm
- https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/duplicate-cleaner-free/9nblggh4rrr3
- **https://sourceforge.net/projects/gdupfinder/**

Answer (score 2):

I had the same use-case, and I wrote up a nifty little script to achieve that end.

Have a look if this Python script helps you too:

https://github.com/AnirudhKishan/DeleteVisuallyRedundant

Comment: It relies on [findimagedupes](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/findimagedupes.1p.html)

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago, in Ubuntu 10.04, I was using [DupeGuru](https://dupeguru.voltaicideas.net/) Picture Edition for that. It was pretty good at finding duplicates in various sizes & resolutions. Seems that since version 4.0 of DupeGuru, the Picture Edition as a separate application is gone, but its functionality has been incorporated into the main application as "Picture Mode". You can try it, however currently only [packages for Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04](https://launchpad.net/%7Edupeguru/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages) are available, there's no build for 20.04.

The package for 18.04 works under 20.04, but some additional fixes after installation are needed. You need to do the following commands:

```
cd /usr/share/dupeguru/core/pe
sudo ln -s _block.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so _block.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
sudo ln -s _cache.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so _cache.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
cd /usr/share/dupeguru/qt/pe
sudo ln -s _block_qt.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so _block_qt.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

After this, DupeGuru works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

[**digiKam**](https://www.digikam.org/) seems to be the answer for me. **Much** more powerful than [<s>*Shotwell*</s>](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Shotwell):

> Tools > **Find Duplicates** (Ctrl D) > *... [generate/update
>   **Fingerprints**] ...* > "**Similarity range**" ~ 95%.

To find "lower resolution duplicates" the similarity range must ***not*** be set to 100%, but fairly close, e.g. 95%.

Comment: Well, though it finds the duplicates alright there seems to be no button to delete all except for the "reference image"; so no "batch" delete all duplicates. That's quite a shame and almost feels like back to square one... :-/