# Command-line utility to find and prompt to delete duplicate images (including resized ones) similar to fdupes?

Tags: command-line, bash, software-recommendation, image-processing, duplicate-files

I am looking for a command-line utility to find duplicate images (*including* resized ones) and prompt me to choose which one to delete.

My cloud backup process seems to generate photo duplicates, some of which seem to be thumbnail-sized resized versions.

I had found and been using `fdupes` with the `--delete` parameter for prompting delete of duplicates, which worked really well for me (I'm worried about data loss so I prefer to be prompted) until I noticed the resized versions also being generated. I am looking for an equivalent to `fdupes` that *also* finds resized images so I can delete the auto-generated thumbnails.

Is there an equivalent to `fdupes . --delete` which also works for resized images?

I found `findimagedupes` from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/4076/152759) which detects resized images but it doesn't appear to have a mode that prompts the user to delete duplicates for particular image sets. It also appears to detect very similar photos (e.g. ones taken right after each other) in default settings.

Comment: Is this a useful starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596262/image-fingerprint-to-compare-similarity-of-many-images ?

Comment: Did you try the other tools listed there? Did none of them work? The answer you linked to is probably the best you can do. Albeit a bit old.

Comment: I just closed this as a duplicate to the one you linked to since it's the same question. Any new solution to this question should be added to those listed there.